# UITableView Sections. Для каждой ячейки - секция с заголовком

Tags: ios, uitableview

Добрый день!

Таблица заполняется данными с массива. В массиве есть заголовки ячейки, который должны отображаться в секции. Для каждой ячейки необходимо добавить новую секцию.

```
    @implementation ViewController{
    NSArray *tableCellTitle;
    NSArray *sectionsTitle;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    tableCellTitle = [NSArray new];
    tableCellTitle = @[@"Cell 1", @"Cell 2", @"Cell 3", @"Cell 4"];

    sectionsTitle = [NSArray new];
    sectionsTitle = @[@"Section 1", @"Section 2", @"Section 3", @"Section 4"];


}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [tableCellTitle count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"TableCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [tableCellTitle objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [sectionsTitle objectAtIndex:section];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался.

```
cell.textLabel.text = [tableCellTitle objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
```

Answer (score 0):

Очевидно, что если для каждой ячейки нужна секция с заголовком, то метод должен выглядеть так:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
   return 1;
}
```

а вот numberOfSectionsInTableView должен, вероятно, быть таким:

```
    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
        PFObject *Object = [array objectAtIndex:section];

        NSString *sectionsTitles = Object[@"TitleCell"];
        NSArray *sections = [Object objectForKey:sectionsTitles];
//      для уверенности давайте прямо тут выведем все, что нам интересно:
        NSLog(@"\n array: %@\n object: %@\n sectionTitles: %@\n sections: %@", array, Object, sectionsTitles, sections);
        return sections.count;
    }
```

если покажете код откуда берется `array` может быть станет совсем понятно

Comment: Спасибо большое! Попробую

Comment: Что-то тут не правильно. в методе - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView не может быть переменной section

Comment: @AlexeySlivkin вы подробнее расскажите про структура объектов в Object, так сложно сказать. Быть может кинете NSLog("Object = %@", Object)?

Comment: Отредактировал. Сейчас выводится 4 секции, но все 4 ячейки - первые(одинаковые)